# ¿Como borrar repositorio en git?

Tags: git, vscode

Buen día.

Tengo un problema para borrar el repositorio, al ejecutar el comando git status, me notifica que tengo un directorio con cambios.

No he logrado borrar dichos cambios, aplique el comando git clean para borra los directorios y aun sigue mostrándose el Untracked.

Dicho repositorio ya lo borre manualmente en la carpeta donde estaba alojado.

[image: Problema con repositorio]

[image: El repositorio ya no se encuentra]

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No logro entender que quieres hacer, ¿quieres borrar los cambios, el repositorio o quitar por completo el versionamiento (git)?

Comment: Lo que paso es que accidentalmente clone otro repositorio, ademas del origin que habia, entonces quiero borrar el que accidentalmente clone, como habia indicado antes en la carpeta ya no esta, pero sigue apareciendo ese path en git status.

Comment: Oh, pues la forma mas sencilla borrar todo y despues volver a clonear el primer repo (el correcto), porque por lo que entiendo tu segundo clone sobrescribió el .git del primero.